# How get List from Set and Comparator

Tags: java, list, set, comparator

What is the "good" (and why ?) solution to get a `List` from a `Set` and sorted against a given `Comparator` ?

Comment: This question is unclear.  For instance, I can get a List from a Set and a Comparator by ignoring the Comparator.  That's a "good" solution ... in the sense that it is faster than solutions that use the Comparator.

Comment: Are you sure you need a List? Maybe a SortedSet would do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();

// add stuff

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(set);
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: just Added COllections.sort() after that.

Comment: Wrong answer, this won't work as ArrayList constructor doesn't sort anything, you haven't even used your Comparator, so how will be it sorted? Use either Collections.sort() or TreeSet, as in other answers.

Comment: Have fixed the answer to include the call to sort.

Answer (score 6):

Just construct it. The `ArrayList` has a [constructor taking another `Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
Set<Foo> set = new TreeSet<Foo>(new FooComparator<Foo>());
// Fill it.

List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>(set);
// Here's your list with items in the same order as the original set.
```

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
Set<X> sortedSet = new TreeSet<X>(comparator); ...
List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>(sortedSet);
```

or:

```
Set<X> unsortedSet = new HashSet<X>(); ...
List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>(unsortedSet);
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you start with an unsorted set or a set sorted on a different order, the following is probably the most efficient assuming that you require a modifiable List.

```
Set<T> unsortedSet = ... 
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(unsortedSet); 
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

If an unmodifiable List is acceptable, then the following is a bit faster:

```
Set<T> unsortedSet = ... 
T[] array = new T[unsortedSet.size()];
unsortedSet.toArray(array);
Arrays.sort(array, comparator);
List<T> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

In the first version, `Collections.sort(...)` copies the list contents to an array, sorts the array, and copies the sorted elements back to the list.  The second version is faster because it doesn't need to copy the sorted elements.

But to be honest the performance difference is probably not significant.  Indeed, as the input set sizes get larger, the performance will be dominated by the `O(NlogN)` time to do the sorting.  The copying steps are `O(N)` and will reduce in importance as N grows.

Comment: Your version with Arrays.sort in fact doesn't optimize much (or even nothing), because Collections.sort() already contains similar code:

    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator)c);
    ListIterator i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set(a[j]);
    }

Comment: @iirekm - using `Arrays.asList(array)` avoids the copying performed using the list iterator.

Comment: Aaah, such extra copying may be important only for very large data sets.

Comment: @iirekm - yes.  But as I mentioned, as N gets really large, the cost of sorting dominates the cost of copying.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get a `List` when you have a `Set`:

```
List list = new ArrayList(set);
```

Not sure what you expect to do with the `Comparator`. If the `Set` is sorted, the list will contain the elements in sorted order.

Comment: Obviously he expects to use the comparator to get a sorted list, implying that the set is unsorted. What else would you use a comparator for? So he should either go via a sorted set or sort the list after populating it.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström - or sort it when/by inserting the elements one by one : insertion sort.

Comment: @Ishtar: Which is what happens if you go via a sorted set, my first suggestion.