# Is it possible to convert a Set into a List?

Tags: java, list, set

I have a function that is supposed to return a list. The function is supposed to suggest different words when it parses through a file and identifies misspelled words. I must return a List. However, when I do so, I end up getting the same word suggested over and over again. I realize storing the "suggested" words in a Set would fix this problem (that way I only store one instance of any given suggestion). The only issue with that is I cannot return that Set since the return type is a List (and again I cannot change this). Is there a way around this issue?

I will provide the function below.

```
public static List<String> getSuggestions(String word){
    List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
                                       "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
                                       "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
                                       "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"); 
    Set<String> suggestions = new HashSet();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(word); 
    for(int i = 0; i <= builder.length(); i++){
        for(String string: letters){
            StringBuilder suggestion = new StringBuilder(builder.toString());
            suggestion.insert(i, string); 
            if(dictionary.contains(suggestion.toString().toLowerCase())){
                suggestions.add(suggestion.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= builder.length()-2; i++){
        for(String string: letters){
            StringBuilder suggestion = new StringBuilder(builder.toString());
            char one = suggestion.charAt(i + 1);
            char two = suggestion.charAt(i);
            suggestion.replace(i, i + 1, String.valueOf(one));
            suggestion.replace(i+1, i + 2, String.valueOf(two));
            if(dictionary.contains(suggestion.toString().toLowerCase())){
                suggestions.add(suggestion.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= builder.length(); i++){
        for(String string: letters){
            StringBuilder suggestion = new StringBuilder(builder.toString());
            suggestion.replace(i, i + 1, "");
            if(dictionary.contains(suggestion.toString().toLowerCase())){
                suggestions.add(suggestion.toString());
            }
        }
   }
   return suggestions;
}
```

Comment: a simple google search of `java convert set to list` gave me about a hundred million results

Comment: *gave me about a hundred million results* - is that all?

Comment: This one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923429/how-get-list-from-set-and-comparator

Comment: I would suggest you to do your 3 stuff in the same double-loop, and avoid to loop 3 times over the same thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want everything in-order change

```
Set<String> suggestions = new HashSet();
```

to

```
Set<String> suggestions = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

And then change your final `return` from

```
return suggestions;
```

to

```
return new ArrayList<String>(suggestions);
```

Comment: Rare to see you answering when there is some duplicates to point out ;)

Comment: @azro Not familiar with 100% of questions on the site!

Comment: right, as am I, but this is sound as a basic just that. move on, have a nice day ;)